# How to access UITableViewCell from UITableView in different UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have very complex cell in `UITableView` within `UIViewControllerA`. Now I need to use the same cell within `UITableView` of `UIViewControllerB`.

1. How to do this without copy and paste views from one scene to another?
2. I don't want to use xib approach.
3. Is it related to `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier`?

Comment: Do you need to use the same cell or just the same information?

Comment: The same prototype of cell.

Comment: How did you create the prototype? You should be able to use `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` if you didn't create it using a nib/xib or storyboard.

Comment: Do you know index of cell you need?

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned you don't want to use `xib`. Storyboards don't support this and therefore the last option you have is to construct your `UITableViewCell` in code. With the new *Auto Layout* anchors, it's not that bad.